# Snapshot google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, snapshot

When I run this command, the first time it makes a full disk snapshot:

```
gcloud compute disks snapshot mydisk1 –-zone=asia-east1-a
```

but the next time it only save the modified data.

Is it possible to change this command to always create a full disk snapshot? Or there is another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this GCP public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) states, Snapshots are incremental and automatically compressed, so you can create regular snapshots on a persistent disk faster and at a much lower cost than if you regularly created a full image of the disk:

1. The first successful snapshot of a persistent disk is a full snapshot that contains all the data on the persistent disk.
2. The second snapshot only contains any new data or modified data since the first snapshot. Data that hasn't changed since snapshot 1 isn't included. Instead, snapshot 2 contains references to snapshot 1 for any unchanged data.
3. Snapshot 3 contains any new or changed data since snapshot 2 but won't contain any unchanged data from snapshot 1 or 2. Instead, snapshot 3 contains references to blocks in snapshot 1 and snapshot 2 for any unchanged data.

There are several advantages to using above backup system:

1. It takes more time to create a full disk snapshot which can degrade system performance. This may be a negative factor for a production system serving thousands of users.
2. Recovering your lost data from a point in time is easier and faster if you do it from an incremental part of your full snapshot backup.

If you want to have full copies of your VM disks regularly, you can consider creating custom images of your (boot) disks, as explained in this public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images).

Answer (score 3):

As described on [Google public doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) Snapshots are always created based on the last successful snapshot as long as the snapshot names are the same. You may try changing the name of your second snapshot.

```
gcloud compute --project=[PROJECT-NAME] disks snapshot [SOURCE-DISK] --zone=us-east1-d --snapshot-names=Mydisk2
```